# How to Convert KeyValuePair to Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

How does one convert a `KeyValuePair` to a `Dictionary`, given that `ToDictionary` is not available in C#?

Comment: Isn't it? Well you could just use `var dict = new Dictionary<KeyType, ValueType>()` then `dict.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value)`

Comment: Do a loop and add each KeyValuePair in a new Dictionary.

Comment: Not duplicate, he asks without `ToDictionary()`.

Comment: It is a duplicate, Robin incorrectly says C# has no ToDictionary

Comment: @JasonEvans Strictly, it's not a dupe - he is asking how to convert a KeyValuePair, not a List[KeyValuePair]. Of course, this does demand the question "Why does he want to do this"?!!

Comment: @doctorlove KeyValuePair does not have a ToDictionary method - it's on IEnumerable, and the question (as written) is not talking about an IEnumerable.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> { { kvp.Key, kvp.Value } };
```

`ToDictionary` *does* exist in C# (edit: not the same `ToDictionary` you were thinking of) and can be used like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>{kvp};
var dictionary = list.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Here `list` could be a `List` or other `IEnumerable` of anything. The first lambda shows how to extract the key from a list item, and the second shows how to extract the value. In this case they are both trivial.

Comment: how can I do that with C# 2.0

Comment: Please add note that you need to use System.Linq

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly you can do it as follows:

```
new[] { keyValuePair }.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary() extension method to convert a collection of one or more KeyValuePairs

```
Dictionary<string,string> result = new[] {  
    new KeyValuePair ("Key1", "Value1"),
    new KeyValuePair ("Key2", "Value2") 
}.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a collection of [KeyValuePair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx) and make sure System.Linq is imported in a `using` statement.

Then you will be able to see the .[ToDictionary()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx) extension method.

```
public IList<KeyValuePair<string, object>> MyDictionary { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to .net 5 or higher and pass them to the constructor:

```
    var x = new Dictionary<string, string>(new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key1", "val1"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("key2", "val2") });
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement it yourself as an extension method.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{

    public static Dictionary<T1,T2> ToDictionary<T1, T2>(this KeyValuePair<T1, T2> kvp)
    {
      var dict = new Dictionary<T1, T2>();
      dict.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
      return dict;
    }

}
```

see this in action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ka54t7

Comment: It may not be obvious to some people that the above code cannot be used as-is: One would need to substitute the actual type for T1 and T2, such as string and object...

Comment: Oh no, I just forgot one bit

Comment: Jazimov. T1 & T2 are generic type references. You would not substitute them. They are inferred by the KeyValuePair instance being extended.

With that said, while this literally answers the question, it isn't useful because you're creating a dictionary collection with only 1 item in its collection. It would be better to extend an IEnumerable of KeyValuePairs, like an array or List.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively (if you can't use Linq.. although I'm curious why..).. implement `ToDictionary` yourself...

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector) {
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }
    if (keySelector == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("keySelector");
    }
    if (elementSelector == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("elementSelector");
    }

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TElement>();
    foreach (TSource current in source) {
        dictionary.Add(keySelector(current), elementSelector(current));
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

Example usage:

```
var kvpList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>(){
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "Item 1"),
    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "Item 2"),
};

var dict = ToDictionary(kvpList, x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```